# Why doesn't loading a file using the classpath loader and the 'classpath:' prefix work?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, classpath

I'm trying to load a file using the classpath loader from within a Spring Boot application.

I'm just running it using Intellij.

It won't load, even though the file is in the resources folder.

Comment: The file probably isn't where you think it is. How are you doing the loading? property source, manual, resource loader? What is it you are trying to do, that is not clear from your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the comment. I was so frustrated with this issue that I created a question and answered it to save other people from it! I've answered it below.

Comment: The file was being loaded by a classpath file loader from deep inside a library I was using. The example code for the library referenced the file in a configuration file with classpath:filename.ext. The example used the resources folder, the same as I did, so I think the example was misleading.

Comment: As mentioned if `src/main/resources` is part of that directory your setup is wrong as it shouldn't. Things from `src/main/resources` are by default copied to to root of the classpath (just as `src/main/java` is being compiled to the root of the classpath).

Answer (score -1):

This was due to the maven project configuration in the `pom.xml` file.

The fix was to include the file I wanted to reference in the build output.

Example `pom.xml` change:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <includes>
      <include>**/filename.ext</include>
    </includes>
  </resources>
</build>
```

The file then appears at: `./target/classes/filename.ext`.

This then means I could reference the file as expected in my application configuration `.yaml` file as follows:

`filename: classpath:filename.ext`

---

Note: this answer was changed from the original.

Comment: `src/main/resources` shouldn't be part of the classpath path, but rather the root of the classpath. If that isn't the case your setup of the project is wrong. So your solution isn't the solution but rather a workaround for a wrongly setup gradle or maven build.

Comment: The classpath was `.\target\classes`. The actual file was in a subdirectory.  The solution worked for the library I am using. I created the question (and answer) to help other people who might have a similar problem.

Comment: It shouldn't be, if that is the case, as mentioned, your gradle/maven setup is wrong. `src/main/resources` is the root of the classpath.

Comment: Is that documented somewhere? I'd be happy to update the answer.

Comment: That is the project structure as laid out by Maven and Gradle and is in their respective documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments. I've updated the original answer to be more useful to other users.

Comment: That isn't a proper answer either, as you shouldn't need to do the including at all. There is something else that is fishy about your build.